# Import Excel to Mysql using Spring MVC

Tags: java, mysql, excel, spring, apache-poi

i'm beginner in spring mvc,

i have success to generate sql to excel using POI , but no i want import excel file to mysql , i've trying much tutorial for doing this action , but still not work. !

there is some best tuts i try, but i'm still failed:

> [Conversion of excel data to MySql tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346607/conversion-of-excel-data-to-mysql-tables)

[Upload Excel file into database using Apache POI and Spring framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740727/upload-excel-file-into-database-using-apache-poi-and-spring-framework)

, Can somebody explain to me step by step to import excel file to mysql sing Spring MVC and POI ?

~thank you ^^
have a great day !

Comment: You might want to add your non working code, as is this is too broad

Comment: i've no idea , i just following the tutorial ..kekeke :p

Comment: post your code here. No worries if its not working. Dont forget to post your error message as well

Comment: allright ,, everyone , i'll post it, thanks :)